# how to pass array object as parameter in angular 6 api call

Tags: angular, typescript

In the following code, `companyId` is an array of objects, and I want to pass this as parameter of an API call, how can I do that ?

```
getItems(): void {
    this.urlcall()
        .subscribe(
        restItems => {
            this.vehicle = restItems;
            console.log('Vehicle Data=',this.vehicle);
        });
}

urlcall() {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.Url, { responseType : 'json',params : this.params ,headers : this.httpHeaders } )
       .pipe(map(data => data));
}

public params = new HttpParams()
    .set('CompanyID',  this.companyID )
    .set('vehicleId', '23')
    .set('currentOdometer', this.cOdometer);

public httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders() 
    .set('Accept','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Comment: you want to pass these as a query params?

Comment: Showing the data that is currently being sent/ expected to be sent through `params` in your `urlcall()` would be helpful

Comment: i dont know how to pass the array variable (companyId ) as params ;

Comment: @vishnuprasath may be you need try with first `stringify` your `object` with JSON.stringify() then use `encodeURI(stringify Obj)` and send it in url but for best practice and security concern you must send these data with request body for that you need to change you api GET to POST. I hope this will helps